# jquery: filter using AND OR in selector

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

My javascript skills are not so good and i am running into the following problem:
I have a 3 filters in my html productlisting page: brands, colors and sizes. When i select one of the brand category options, only the products from selected brand need to display. When I click on another (second) brand, all products of both selected brands need to dislay (brand A OR Brand B). Now this works ok. However when i click on oen of the other filtercategories (eg one of the colors or sizes) it goes wrong: both selected brands are being displayed but also all other brands that correspond to the size that i select. So instead of it showing only the products of the two brands selected and then only the selected size, it shows both brand products and all the products that have that size, including other brands that have the size.  It seems that my current filter function behaves as an OR function:

hide(all); 
show(brand1 OR brand2 OR color1);

What i want it to behave like  is:

hide(all);
show((brand1 OR brand2) AND (color1))

For the complete reference: I would like the javasript function to perform as follow:

hide(all); 
show((brand1 OR brand2 OR brand3) AND (color1 OR color 2 OR color3) AND (size1 OR size2 OR size3)); (if all are selected) etc...

So within the same filter category (eg brands) evaluate which arguments to show with OR, but between categories evaluate with AND

The filter works by looking at a div's data-attributes using a jquery script

This is the code:

filter blocks:

```js
$('#filter-wrap-filters').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
 var $lis = $('#clothes > div'),
  $checked = $('input:checked'); 
 if ($checked.length) {       
        var selector = '';
        $($checked).each(function(index, element){
   if(selector === '') {
    selector += "[data-filters~='" + element.id + "']";                  
   } else {
    selector += ",[data-filters~='" + element.id + "']";
   }
        });                        
  $lis.hide(); 
        console.log(selector);
  $('#clothes > div').hide().filter(selector).show();      
 } else {
  $lis.show();
 }
});
/*CREDITS TO http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/1/ */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter-wrap-filters" >
<div style="float:left;">
<span>Select Sizes</span><br />
<form>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="xs" class="checkbox" />XS</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="s" class="checkbox" />S</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="m" class="checkbox" />M</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="l" class="checkbox" />L</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="xl" class="checkbox" />XL</label><br /> 
</form>
</div>

<div style="float:left;">
<span>Select Colors</span><br />
<form>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="black" class="checkbox" />Black</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="white" class="checkbox" />White</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="grey" class="checkbox" />Grey</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="orange" class="checkbox" />Orange</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="pink" class="checkbox" />Pink</label><br /> 
</form>
</div>

<div style="float:left;">
<span>Select brands</span><br />
<form>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="branda" class="checkbox" />a</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="brandb" class="checkbox" />b</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="brandc" class="checkbox" />c</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="brandd" class="checkbox" />d</label><br />
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="brande" class="checkbox" />e</label><br /> 
</form>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<!--PRODUCT LISTING BELOW -->
<div id="clothes">
  <div class="custom-container-listing" data-filters="branda black white s m ">
  product 1 - brand A - color Black, White - size S,M
  </div>
</div>

<div id="clothes">
  <div class="custom-container-listing" data-filters="brandb white pink m l ">
  product 2 - brand B - color White, Pink - size M, L
  </div>
</div>

<div id="clothes">
  <div class="custom-container-listing" data-filters="brandc orange grey l xl ">
  product 3 - brand C - color Orange, Grey - size L,XL
  </div>
</div>

<div id="clothes">
  <div class="custom-container-listing" data-filters="brandb orange pink s xl ">
  product 4 - brand B - color Orange, Pink - size S,XL
  </div>
</div>
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me change the javascript function to perform the way i want because i don't know how to change it.

Comment: can you give an example selection of the above options to determine what is the correct output from the provided example.

Comment: select brand a and brand b. you see then product 1,2 and 4 become visible. If I then select the color pink, i would expect product 1 to hide, because it doesnt have the color pink. it should display Brand A and B products that also have color pink. I hope this makes it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant solutions, but if I understand correctly, concatenating in one single selector will match all of them (as the current behavior).

I created a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pm7fvauq/1/) for you to see, basically I filter for each type with only the results other filters.

```
$lis.hide();
$lis = filter($lis, 'color');
$lis = filter($lis, 'size');
$lis = filter($lis, 'continent');
$lis.show();
```

I had to add one extra class to your checkboxes so I can identify the type of the checkbox

Comment: Wow Thanks for the quick response. i will have to dig deeper into your solution to understand it but i think it already does what i want! Indeed the concatenating in one single selector would match agains all, that is not what i was looking for.

Comment: thanks @valarauko, your solution works like a charm! I am however curious to what more elegant solution you had in mind?

Comment: If combinations give none result , can you "disable" this checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, you would need to iterate each checkbox after the data get's populated, but you would probably want to disable the checkboxes that individually does not have a match since if you use a combination and disable those checkboxes how are you going to recover from that and I might not have XS White Brand B product but I might have a White Brand B product; so when would you reenable those checkboxes (seems kind of odd to disable them); I you want to disable them on the filter clicked you can check the length of the elements $lis.length and then disable the checked checkboxes